# Error using React Select Library Select Component: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am working on a React project, and I am utilizing the react-select library. However, I am unable to use it as it crashes my app. This is probably a very simple mistake, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the error message:
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Here is the relevant code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component} from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select'

export default function Card(props) {
    return (

    <Card>
        <Select />

    </Card>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is this a copy and paste error or are you really using the `Card` component inside itself?  You're going to have an infinite loop!

Comment: Oops! I didn't realize that was crashing it, thanks for the help!